# Android putting all my canvas drawing into another class?

Tags: android

I am delving into the art of android and canvas and I have everything up and running and a little project I am working on! I have created a framework for a canvas loop to display animation the part where I draw to the canvas is as follows;

```
// DRAW TO THE CANVAS
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // CLEAR CANVAS
    canvas.drawColor(Color.YELLOW);
    androidMan.draw(canvas);
            circle.draw(canvas);
            square.draw(canvas);
}
```

All of the 3 objects appear and everything works fine. As I am new to both java and android I would like to put those 3 draw statements into a seperate class if possible so I can have the `onDraw` look something like,

```
// DRAW TO THE CANVAS
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // CLEAR CANVAS
    canvas.drawColor(Color.YELLOW);
    renderCanvas();
}
```

And within render canvas something like

```
androidMan.draw(canvas);
            circle.draw(canvas);
            square.draw(canvas);
```

But when I do this it doesn't work and the app fails to load on my phone, thanks even if the question is stupidly thick! If possible I would like `renderCanvas` to be its own file.

Answer (score 0):

At first, change signature of method renderCanvas

```
renderCanvas(Canvas canvas)
```

And call it like

```
renderCanvas(canvas);
```

Agronomy onDraw.